# How to debug this Binary Search code?

Tags: c

I don't know what's wrong with this binary search code of mine. It seems fine to me, but always displaying "not found" in output. I don't know why. Can someone identify the problem?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define SIZE 100
void binarySearch(int, int*);

int arr[SIZE];
int low = 0, high = SIZE - 1;

int main() {
    int arr[SIZE] = { 10, 47, 67, 78, 95, 99 };
    binarySearch(95, arr);
}

void binarySearch(int key, int *arr) {
    if (arr[low] == key) {
        puts("Found!");
        return;
    }
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = low + (high - 1) / 2;
        if (key == arr[mid]) {
            printf("Data found at index: %d\n", mid);
            return;
        }
        else if (key > arr[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    puts("\nData not found!");
}
```

Comment: Your array of 100 values is not sorted. Lots of zeros at the end!

Comment: Thank you! I have to sort it first. I've forgotten that.

Comment: Questions that request debugging help are OK here, but only if some debugging has been done already. "Debug this for me" doesn't really work very well, mainly because readers want to know why you have apparently not tried anything at all. Of course, you probably _have_ tried something, but we can only go on what we see. The key thing to remember about debugging is that **if something seems confusing, it is because you've not broken it down enough**. So, break it down, add debug statements, examine where unexpected values are being introduced.

Comment: Your function needs the actual size. SIZE is the max size, so maybe rename it to that (or just use std::vector). Your function also needs its own local variables for low and high, otherwise it will fail spectacularly if you try to search a second time. And I'm not sure if mid actually has the right value when low==high in your code (but I didn't run it to be sure of that).

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your array is sorted here, initializing high to a constant value of SIZE (100) is the problem. If you trace the values of low and high in iterations, you will know that. Instead you can use this:

```
int arr[] = {10, 47, 67, 78, 95, 99};
int n = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
```

and pass n to the function and initialize high = n-1.